# week dates skip when iterating with time delta

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.today() #datetime type
n = today.weekday() #integer type

if(n == 5 or n == 6):
    if(n == 5):
        Monday = today + timedelta(days = 2)
    else:
        Monday = today + timedelta(days = 1)
else: 
       
    Monday = today - timedelta(n) 
    Friday = Monday + timedelta(days = 4)
    this = [0, 1, 2]
    for a in this:
        Monday = Monday + timedelta(weeks = a)    
        Friday = Friday + timedelta(weeks = a) #find out why it skips weeks 
        print(Monday)
        print(Friday)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what `a` equals each loop and what `+ timedelta(weeks = a)` would do.  It skips because you are incrementing the Monday and Friday variables by 0 weeks the first pass, 1 week the second pass, then *2 weeks* the third pass.

Just increment by 1 week each pass.  Also fixed/simplified the Saturday/Sunday test which wouldn't print anything in the original code.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
n = today.weekday() # Monday = 0, Sunday = 6

if n > 4:  # Saturday or Sunday advance to next Monday
    Monday = today + timedelta(days = 7-n)
else:      # else go back to current week Monday
    Monday = today - timedelta(n) 

Friday = Monday + timedelta(days = 4)

for _ in range(5):
    print(f'{Monday:%Y-%m-%d} to {Friday:%Y-%m-%d}')
    Monday += timedelta(weeks = 1)    
    Friday += timedelta(weeks = 1)
```

Output:

```
2021-06-21 to 2021-06-25
2021-06-28 to 2021-07-02
2021-07-05 to 2021-07-09
2021-07-12 to 2021-07-16
2021-07-19 to 2021-07-23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
next_monday = today + timedelta(days=((0 - today.weekday()) % 7))  # 0 is monday

for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    print(*[f'{next_monday + timedelta(weeks=i, days=d):%Y-%m-%d}' for d in [0, 4]], sep='\n')
```

**Output**

```
2021-06-28
2021-07-02
2021-07-05
2021-07-09
2021-07-12
2021-07-16
```